# jQuery: calculate sum of TD values instead of returning text

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, each

I am using the following lines to search through the rows of a table to check if any TDs contain my searchTerm which works fine so far.

My only problem is the case where searchTerm appears more than once in a row (like below). 
In this case it adds the values from a row as text instead of calculating the sum of them.

**Example:** 
Here it currently returns `82,0,5` as searchTerm appears twice in the first row (once with the value 8 and once with 2). 
Instead of this it should return `10,0,5` in this case.

Can anyone tell here me how I have to change my code to achieve this ?

**My JS:**

```
var searchTerm = "item1"
var result = new Array();
    $('#myTable tbody tr').each(function() {
        result.push(+($(this).find('td:contains(' + searchTerm + ')').next('td').text()));
    });
alert(result);
```

**My table:**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 1</th>
            <th>Vol 1</th>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 2</th>
            <th>Vol 2</th>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 3</th>
            <th>Vol 3</th>
            //...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>item1</td><td>8</td><td>item2</td><td>7</td><td>item1</td><td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item3</td><td>5</td><td>item2</td><td>7</td><td>item2</td><td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item3</td><td>1</td><td>item1</td><td>5</td><td>item3</td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
        //...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: Convert the text into Integer using parseInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
var xSum = 0;

$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function() {
       xSum = 0;
    $(this).find('td:contains(' + searchTerm + ')').each(function(){
       xSum += parseInt($(this).next('td').text());
    });
    result.push(xSum);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pGGR8/1/)